# How does this code find the rectangle intersection?

Tags: ruby, intersection

This code finds the intersection of two rectangles, but I can't fully comprehend it. When I try to map it on paper, it doesn't even make a rectangle:

```
def rec_intersection(rect1, rect2)
  x_min = [rect1[0][0], rect2[0][1]].max
  x_max = [rect1[1][0], rect2[1][1]].min
  y_min = [rect1[0][0], rect2[0][1]].max
  y_max = [rect1[1][0], rect2[1][1]].min
  return nil if ((x_max < x_min) || (y_max < y_min))
  return [[x_min, y_min], [x_max, y_max]]
end

rec_intersection([[1, 1], [2, 2]],[[0, 0], [5, 5]])
```

The code above returns `[[1, 1], [2, 2]]`. Can someone explain the process?

Comment: Myself not understood,what is the problem?

Comment: @SperanskyDanil Hehe Nice one :)

Comment: The code is suppose to return the intersection point of 2 rectangles. Rect1 and rect2.  I don't understand how it flows so I am asking someone to clarify. thanks

Comment: This code have an error. `rec_intersection([[6, 2], [8, 4]],[[2, 6], [4, 8]])` will return `[[6, 6], [8, 8]]`. The answer below fixed this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to see code written a little differently:

```
def rec_intersection(rect1, rect2)

  x_min = [rect1.top_left.x, rect2.top_left.x].max # => 1
  y_min = [rect1.top_left.y, rect2.top_left.y].max # => 1

  x_max = [rect1.bottom_right.x, rect2.bottom_right.x].min # => 2
  y_max = [rect1.bottom_right.y, rect2.bottom_right.y].min # => 2

  Rectangle.new(
    Point.new(x_min, y_min),
    Point.new(x_max, y_max)
  )

end

Point = Struct.new(:x, :y)
Rectangle = Struct.new(:top_left, :bottom_right)

rect1 = Rectangle.new(Point.new(1, 1), Point.new(2, 2))
# => #<struct Rectangle
#     top_left=#<struct Point x=1, y=1>,
#     bottom_right=#<struct Point x=2, y=2>>

rect2 = Rectangle.new(Point.new(0, 0), Point.new(5, 5))
# => #<struct Rectangle
#     top_left=#<struct Point x=0, y=0>,
#     bottom_right=#<struct Point x=5, y=5>>

rec_intersection(rect1, rect2)
# => #<struct Rectangle
#     top_left=#<struct Point x=1, y=1>,
#     bottom_right=#<struct Point x=2, y=2>>
```

Comment: `[rect1[0][0], rect2[0][1]].max` does not match to `[rect1.top_left.x, rect2.top_left.x].max`. Should be `rect2[0][0]`